# How to set a vector's type based on user input

Tags: c++, vector

I want to avoid writing the whole program for different types. This is how the code looks now:

```
switch(e) {
    case('i'): {            // if the user wants integers:
        std::vector<long double> v(b);
        std::cout << "\nEnter the Minimum Size for the numbers: ";
        std::cin >> c;
        std::cout << "\nEnter the Maximum Size for the numbers: ";
        std::cin >> d;
        for (i = 0; i <= b-1; i++)
            a[i] = random_int(c, d);
        .
        .
        .
        sort(a.data(), 0,b-1);
        break;
    }

    case('d'): {           // if the user wants decimal numbers:
        std::vector<long double> v(b);
        std::cout << "\nEnter the Minimum Size for the numbers: ";
        std::cin >> m;
        std::cout << "\nEnter the Maximum Size for the numbers: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i <= b-1; i++)
            a[i] = random_float(m, n);
        .
        .
        .
        sort(v.data(), 0,b-1);
        break;
    }

    default: {
        goto loop;
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's needlessly long.

Changing the vector's type doesn't seem to work (leaned it the hard way) and I can't make a function for making the vector because of the `random_int` / `random_float` part (they use `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `std::uniform_real_distribution`).

Comment: goto... long lost enemy.

Comment: "changing a vector type in C++" is a completely meaningless statement. I find nothing in the shown code that can be remotely described as "changing a vector type", in any way.

Comment: I assume you want to return one and the same type in each of the switch cases?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
Are you blind or something? read the code after case('d')

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider
I want to return a vector based on user input. that's all.

Comment: C++ has static typing, the types have to be known at compile time. You can make a `union` of a bunch of types, make a `vector` of `union`s, remember which one is active and do a lot of `switch`/`case` all over your code. I'd recommend to just use a `vector<double>` for everything and be done at it.

Comment: What you want is called a "discriminated union", that is, a class that can hold one of two types of values and knows which it is holding. You can implement such a class however you want. But perhaps a better idea is to figure out all the operations you need and implement them polymorphicly.

Comment: Saleh, moderate your tone. This is a badly worded question, and we are trying to help. You make us sorry for reading this.

Comment: If all choices are arithmetic types your easiest bet may be to just resort to a vector of doubles (doubles can hold consecutive ints up to 2^52 or so).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider
Sorry. I just want people to actually read my question before answering.

Comment: The code after "case('d')" accomplishes absolutely nothing that can be remotely described as "changing a vector type". A vector's type cannot be changed any more that you can change your own name.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider
So there isn't a way to switch a "long long int" type with a "long double" type?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
Thank you for answering.

Comment: Even the swap should only work for vectors with exactly the same element type, pointer or not.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider
I know. The comment was written at least 2 weeks ago when I started changing the code.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider
By the way should I delete my question? It seems It's not really helpful....

Comment: You shouldn't delete your question, if it was delete-worthy it would have already been so a long time ago.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik:  Really bad analogy.  Changing your own name is not hard.  Better perhaps "changing who your biological parents are".

Comment: @MartinBonner In Germany it's really hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, and there is no one "best way". But the most straightforward way is probably to use inheritance. Make a list of all the behavior that has to change based on the type and implement functions for each of them. Implement them polymorphicly. For example:

```
class IntOrDouble
{
    public:
    bool isInt() const { return _isInt; }
    bool isDouble() const { return !_isInt; }
    int getAsInt() const; // throws if not integer
    double getAsDouble() const; // throws if not double

    protected:
    bool _isInt;
    int _valueIfInt;
    double _valueIfDouble;
};

class VectorOfIntsOrDoubles
{
    public:

    void makeVectorOfInts(); // must be empty
    void makeVectorOfDoubles(); // must be empty

    // Reads an IntOrDouble of the appropriate type for this container
    IntOrDouble ReadValue() const;

    // Generates a random IntOrDouble of the appropriate type for this container
    IntOrDouble GenRandom() const;

    private:
    bool _isInts;
    std::vector <IntOrDouble> _vector;
};
```

And so on.

Comment: Although my intuitive design would be to not introduce a new arithmetic "union type" but just specify an abstract base class with accessors for int, double etc. (which throw in an implementation if it's not that type), plus a factory function which branches to create an instance of one of several implementing classes which each hold a simple vector of the desired element type. And in all reality. for arithmetic types one could probably get away with a template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (Man, I got myself into a big problem...)

Comment: @SalehShamloo Polymorphism is one of the major reasons for having classes.

Answer (score 0):

Another polymorphic approach. First we define an abstract base class which is what most parts of the program only will ever know. It only defines access functions to the data and doesn't hold any (except the `kind` type tag). Most access function implementations of the derived classes will simply throw at run time, except the ones which are proper for the data type of the elements:

```
/// The type which will alwys be returned
class VecHolder
{
    public:
    enum kindE { INTVEC, DBLVEC, /*...*/} ;

    kindE kind;

    VecHolder(kindE k) : kind(k) {}

    /// These expose the vectors for simplicity. The derived classes
    /// will hold just one of them.
    virtual vector<int> &intVec() = 0;
    virtual vector<double> &dblVec() = 0;
    // ...

    static VecHolder *MakeVec(kindE kind);
};
```

Now we'll show two concrete implementations, for double and for int:

```
/// An implementation for int elements
class IntVecHolder: public VecHolder
{
    public:

    IntVecHolder() : VecHolder(INTVEC) {} 
    vector<int> &intVec() { return vec; };
    vector<double> &dblVec()  { throw exception();}

    protected:
    vector<int> vec;

};

/// An implementation for double elements
class DblVecHolder: public VecHolder
{
    public:

    DblVecHolder() : VecHolder(DBLVEC) {} 

    vector<int> &intVec() { throw exception();}
    vector<double> &dblVec(){ return vec; };

    protected:
    /// This is the actual data (somewhat) hidden behind the 
    /// abstract VecHolder interface.
    vector<double> vec;
};
```

Now that we know these classes we can code the factory function which creates the proper VecHolder implementation based on the user's choice (`kind`):

```
/// The factory function: Exact type of object behind returned
/// pointer dpends on parameter, but they are all derived from VecHolder
VecHolder *VecHolder::MakeVec(kindE kind)
{
    switch(kind)
    {
        case INTVEC: return new IntVecHolder; break;
        case DBLVEC: return new DblVecHolder; break;
    }
}
```

Last not least, here is an example use. I find it more awkward than I imagined -- the user code always must discriminate according to the `kind` of the holder. Of course one should hide as much of the ugly switching in functions.

```
int main()
{
    /// An array of vec holder pointers
    VecHolder *vecHolders[] 
        {   VecHolder::MakeVec(VecHolder::DBLVEC),
            VecHolder::MakeVec(VecHolder::INTVEC)
        };

    for( auto &vhp: vecHolders )
    {
        // we always have to discriminate.
        switch(vhp->kind)
        {
            case VecHolder::DBLVEC: vhp->dblVec().push_back(1.0); break;
            case VecHolder::INTVEC: vhp->intVec().push_back(2); break;
        }
    }

    for( auto &vhp: vecHolders )
    {
        switch(vhp->kind)
        {
            case VecHolder::DBLVEC: 
                cout << vhp->dblVec()[0] << endl; 
            break;
            case VecHolder::INTVEC: 
                cout << vhp->intVec()[0] << endl; 
            break;
        }

        // clean up
        delete vhp; 
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o polymorphic-vec polymorphic-vec.cpp && ./polymorphic-vec
1
2
```